# Regular expression for getting parts of a string

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace "after 10 hour" or "after 10 hours" with blank... 
$task_modified variable should print only "remind me to do something"
however with the current code it prints "remind me to do something s"

"s" in the string is not required.... its happening because of the regular expression. "/after\s(\d+)\shour/"

no matter if its one hour or 10 hours, i dont need that extra "s"

```
<?php

$task = "remind me to do something after 10 hours";

if (preg_match("/after\s(\d+)\shour/", $task, $matches) === 1) {
    $hour_after = $matches[1];
    $time_24hr = date('H:i:s',strtotime("+".$hour_after." hours"));

    $task_modified = str_replace($matches[0],"",$task_modified);
}
```

this is what i had tried ... but does not work:

```
/after\s(\d+)\s[hour|hours]/
```

Comment: I think in your regex `"/after\s(\d+)\shour/"` you are only missing to match the `s` at the end optionally. So, your correct regex would look like `/after\s(\d+)\shour(s)?/`. https://3v4l.org/6XXmR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve that using **POSITIVE LOOKAHEAD**

```
$task = "remind me to do something after 10 hours";
preg_match('/(.*)(?=\safter\s(\d+)\s)/mui', $task, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // remind me to do something
echo $matches[2]; // 10
```

Comment: but i also need the value 10 in a variable... in the previous code, the value 10 was in the variable $matches[1];   because i use that value to add to the date.
   


`$time_24hr = date('H:i:s',strtotime("+".$hour_after." hours"));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) without lookarounds:

```
\h+after\h+\d+\h+hours?$
```

**Explanation**

- `\h+after\h+` Match `after` between 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\d+\h+` Match 1+ digits and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `hours?` Match `hour` with an optional `s`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Opdsy/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/LPLvE)

```
$re = '/\h+after\h+\d+\h+hours?$/m';
$task = 'remind me to do something after 10 hours';
$task_modified = preg_replace($re, '', $task);
echo $task_modified;
```

Output

```
remind me to do something
```